# variable realloaction with same size in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables

I am not very expert in Matlab code, so currently I am coding using it and I was wonder if there is a simple way to realloact the variables with same size in matlab:
such as:

```
 A=zeros(length(D),D);
 B=zeros(length(D),D);
 C=zeros(length(D),D);
 D=zeros(length(D),D);
```

which are matrixs result from for loop with changeable size. 
this way is fine, but is there simple way to make this in one single line?? 
I have tried [ A,B,C,D]=zeros(length(D),D);
but it didn't work.

any advice is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When coding in MATLAB, my suggestion is to **always** code for readability.  Once you get it working, then if you can truly assess whether or not optimizations in your code will make it go faster, then go ahead and optimize.  However, I would argue that making those allocations all within a single line of code doesn't really optimize anything.

What's wrong with what you have there?  That is a perfectly valid set of statements and you don't need to do it in a single line.  If you're afraid of typing, you can always set `B`, `C` and `E` to what `A` was assigned to.  Note that I've changed the last line of assigning `D` to `E` as you would be redefining what `D` would be before this statement. I'm assuming this is not your intention.  Also note that `zeros(length(D), D)` is nonsense as `D` I'm assuming is some vector, but you're using it as an argument to `zeros`.  You need to ensure each parameter is a scalar.

Remember that MATLAB performs copies of matrices and doesn't provide references (there are exceptions to this, but we'll not go into that now).  Something like this will work:

```
A = zeros(10, 10);
B = A; C = A; E = A;
```

However, if you really want to do this in one line, you can use [`deal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) to take a single argument and copy it over each output argument you specify:

```
[A,B,C,E] = deal(zeros(10,10));
```

I would argue that it's less readable, but it does what you're asking.

Comment: yes works finally, before i got some error, I used [A,B,C,E] = deal(zeros

Comment: [A,B,C,E] = deal(zeros(length(D),D)) or  [A,B,C,E] = deal(zeros(size(D)) all work fine, Thank you